# Pulling out the files from directories by connecting to ftp using python

Tags: python, ftplib

task: I need to connect to clients FTP, where we have many directories and each directory may or may not have .csv files in it. Now I need to go to each directory and open the files in all directories and if the file is according to the given format then dump in a server.

Presently I'm able to connect to FTP do this much 
I'm able to get the directories list but not the files inside the directory.

```
from ftplib import FTP
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
import sys
import os.path


ftp=FTP('host')
ftp.login('user','pwd')

for files in ftp.dir():
    filenames=ftp.nlst(files)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + a, file.write)
    file.close()


ftp.close()  #CLOSE THE FTP CONNECTION
print "FTP connection closed. Goodbye"
```

I know that is not at all up to the mark.

Comment: For checking the format i hope so chkcsv module can be used

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "then dump in a server", dump what in a server? and are we talking about the same FTP server?

Comment: no fozoro , need to dump in another server.....but right now i m not able to loop through the directories and the files

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are looking for a way to get a list of the files in a given directory. Here is a function I often use to solve this task in unix system (macOS included). It should be a good starting point if not the final solution you are looking for.

```
import glob, os
def list_of_files(path, extension, recursive=False):
    '''
    Return a list of filepaths for each file into path with the target extension.
    If recursive, it will loop over subfolders as well.
    '''
    if not recursive:
        for file_path in glob.iglob(path + '/*.' + extension):
            yield file_path
    else:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file_path in glob.iglob(root + '/*.' + extension):
                yield file_path
```

Also, you can use `ftp.cwd('..')` to change directory and `ftp.retrlines('LIST')` to just get the list of files of that directory.
Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) for some useful code snippet.

Comment: hi, but does this work for the directories or files  present on ftp.Firstly i shall login to ftp credentials then need to proceed with the above you mean

Comment: Of course, FTP is a protocol to transfer files, not a file system. You are probably connecting to a unix machine. So, it should work no problem. I have used it on FTP servers already.

Comment: Hi alec, How can it be applied in my program need, kindly help me out

Comment: Your program is just a snippet. It is not really clear what you want to accomplish. If you send me a private message with your email address, I can send you a python notebook that I use to deal with my FTP servers. You can easily add your server address, user and pw and play with it.

Comment: I really think the command you are looking for is `ftp.retrlines('LIST')`. With that you get the output of a simple `ls` command. You can parse it to get the list of files you are interested in. For example by checking that the extension is `.csv`.